# scanf blocking program in C

Tags: c, scanf

today i've run into a problem i decided to start learning C followed a tutorial and got to a point when my program compiles but just blocks
code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int age;

    printf("Enter your age: ");
    scanf("%d", &age);
    printf("%d", age);
    return 0;
}
```

the following code after compilation doesn't display anything and the program never exits

Comment: Between t he first `printf` and the `scanf` calls, add `fflush(stdout);`. Does that work?

Comment: @n.m. The question doesn’t mention an IDE, what are you getting at?

Comment: Looks like stdout is line buffered, i.e. collects data until a newline. Try with `printf("Enter your age:\n");`.

Comment: It's waiting for input.

Answer (score 2):

Your system seems to require manual flushing the output to `stdout` before attempting to read from `stdin`.  This is usually not necessary but depending on how the IDE is implemented, the mechanism for flushing automatically upon reading may be ineffective.

The `Enter your age:`  prompt is pending in the output stream buffer as the program is already waiting for input to be converted as an `int`, this input from the terminal is line buffered, hence it will only be made available to `scanf()` once the user hits the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int age;

    printf("Enter your age: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    if (scanf("%d", &age) == 1) {
        printf("%d\n", age);
    } else {
        printf("invalid input\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It could be that stdout is line buffered by default. Adding a newline might already fix the problem.

Comment: @Jens: most C libraries determine the default buffering for `stdin` and `stdout` from the type of device they are attached to: line buffered for a terminal or another character device or fully buffered otherwise. There is usually an extra test  that flushes `stdout` (if line buffered) prior to filling the `stdin` buffer.  It appears these provisions are either not present or not effective on the OP's system (most likely an IDE encapsulating the program interaction). Manually flushing `stdout` with `fflush(stdout)` should work in all cases, appending a newline to the prompt may not suffice.